# TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY not copying

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, build

I've just started learning Powershell, but I want to copy the sources directory build environment to a destination folder. I've checked that the environment variable isn't empty. Here's the current code I have:

```
$SourcePath = $Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY
$LastErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Copy-Item $SourcePath "C:\Users\{my username}\Documents" -Recurse -Force
$ErrorActionPreference = $LastErrorActionPreference
Remove-Variable LastErrorActionPreference
```

The builds succeed, but when I check my Documents folder, nothing has been added. Might you have any idea why this is?

Comment: Have you tried removing the changed ErrorActionPreference to see if you get an error message from the Copy-Item call? (Additionally, you would just have specified the ErrorAction parameter on the Copy-Item call instead of changing the preference variable)

Comment: I did actually remove the whole section about ErrorActionPreference, but then I got an access denied error. Is there a better way to change erroractionpreference? I'll give it a try to specify the paramter. Thanks!

Comment: Changing the ErrorActionPreference (or ErrorAction parameter) to SilentlyContinue will only hide problems from you, not solve them. If you get access denied errors then I guess you have permission related issues.

Comment: Ah, so this may be a different issue with permissions, then? Guess I'll need to see if I can fix that. Do you notice anything else weird with my code? Thanks for your help, Robert!

Comment: Not on a quick glance, except setting the ErrorActionPreference variable directly instead of using the ErrorAction parameter. I'd suggest removing the lines 2,3,5 & 6. If you really want the error action changed (but I'd suggest not hiding the errors), use the ErrorAction parameter on the Copy-Item cmdlet.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, I ended up deleting those lines entirely as well. I'll search around for links about changing permissions. Thanks!